# Any way to run the last test ran in Eclipse, whatever the window I'm in at the moment?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, keyboard-shortcuts

I know about ALT + SHIFT + X, T, but that seems only to work if I'm on my test's file.

Is there a way to get it to work even when I'm working on a different file (for instance, in the code file that I want to test)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use always launch the previously launched application.

Preferences --> Run/Debug --> Launching --> always launch the previously launched application.

It would take precedence over normal files programs to and not only tests though. I like it for normal apps to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a Run Configuration for the currently focused file, you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to execute the last Run Configuration, <kbd>F11</kbd> to do the same in Debug mode.